# Array Object File form Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, axios, multipartform-data

How do I send an array of objects contain file to **axios** with formData?

ex..

```
let sponsors = [{
  img: 'file.jpg',
  title: 'Aqua',
  url: 'https://aqua.com'
},
{
  img: 'file2.jpg',
  title: 'TA',
  url: 'https://talkasrul.com'
}]

let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('sponsors', sponsors)

axios({
  url: url,
  data: formData
})
```

Comment: Do you just want to send the file name or the file contents? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You have to serialise the objects *somehow*. The specifics really depend on what format the server is expecting the data in. (And that assumes you want to send the data in the objects, and not read some files from somewhere and then send the contents of those files)

Comment: I want to send that file so that it can be uploaded to the backend, 
the backend accepts an array for processing upload file `[{img: File, title: 'TA', url: 'https://talkasrul.com'}]`

Comment: @AsrulH — The backend might parse some serialised data into an array, but unless we know what serialisation format it expects, knowing that doesn't really help.

Comment: @Quentin, The backend processes the array it receives for uploading by looping. Is there a way to upload files without FormData ?, sorry if this is like a nested question

Comment: @AsrulH — The backend can't process the array until it has an array … which you can't send until you send it a serialised array in a serialisation format that it understands and we still don't know what that is. (And you aren't sending files, you are sending objects containing three strings, one of which looks like a filename).